# MySQL single-row result set, to be repeated with a new value in where statement

Tags: mysql, subquery, resultset

I have a complex query which result is exactly what I need. This query has subqueries, cases, joins, multiple groups, derived tables, aliases and counts/sums  to accomplish what I need. This SQL query works fine but there's a problem: in order for this to get all the info I need I have to set manually an ID:

`where id = 500`

I get a correct row, but I need the table to have this calculations for multiple IDs. Because of my query, I can't change the `group by` nor I can just use an `in (500, 501, 502)` statement because I won't get the results I need and my sums/counts will combine the info returned.

So I need to set that ID as a variable...

Here's the query I have:

```
select id_product as 'ID PRODUCT', brand as 'BRAND', family as 'FAMILY', product as 'PRODUCT',
truncate(min(vp.price),2) as 'MIN',
truncate(max(vp.price),2) as 'MAX',
truncate(avg(vp.price),2) as 'AVERAGE',
(SELECT vp.price 
    FROM visit_prices vp
    WHERE vp.vp_id_product=id_product
    GROUP BY vp.price 
    ORDER BY count(vp.price) DESC 
    LIMIT 1) AS 'MODE',
totalChainsPivoted.`SAMPLE SIZE`,
totalChainsPivoted.`FIRST CATEGORY`,
totalChainsPivoted.`SECOND CATEGORY`,
totalChainsPivoted.`THIRD CATEGORY`,
totalChainsPivoted.`FOURTH CATEGORY`

from visit_prices vp
join table_products pd on vp.vp_id_product = id_product
join sf_family fa on pd.pd_id_family = fa.id_family
join sf_brand ba on fa.fa_ba_id_brand = ba.id_brand

join table_visits vi on vp.vp_id_visit = vi.id_visit
join table_proyects pr on vi.vi_id_proyect = pr.id_proyect

inner join (SELECT totalChainsByProduct.`ID_PROD`,
  sum(totalChainsByProduct.`COUNT`) as 'SAMPLE SIZE', 
  sum(case when totalChainsByProduct.`CHAIN` = 'FIRST CATEGORY'  then totalChainsByProduct.COUNT end) AS FIRSTCATEGORY,
  sum(case when totalChainsByProduct.`CHAIN` = 'SECOND CATEGORY' then totalChainsByProduct.COUNT end) AS SECONDCATEGORY,
  sum(case when totalChainsByProduct.`CHAIN` = 'THIRD CATEGORY' then totalChainsByProduct.COUNT end) AS THIRDCATEGORY,
  sum(case when totalChainsByProduct.`CHAIN` = 'FOURTH CATEGORY' then totalChainsByProduct.COUNT end) AS FOURTHCATEGORY
from (
    select id_product as `ID_PROD`, ch.chain as `CHAIN`, count(ch.chain) as `COUNT`
    from table_visits vi
    join table_proyects pr on vi.vi_id_proyect = pr.id_proyect
    join table_point_of_sale pos on vi.vi_id_pos = pos.id_pos
    join table_formats fo on pos.pos_id_format = fo.id_format
    join table_groups gr on fo.fo_id_group = gr.id_group
    join table_chains ch on gr.gr_id_channel = ch.id_channel
    join visit_prices vp on vp.vp_id_visit = vi.id_visit
    join table_products pd on vp.vp_id_product = id_product 
    where pr.id_proyect = 5 and id_product = 580 /* <--- HERE'S MY PROBLEM!! */ 
    group by ch.id_channel
) as totalChainsByProduct) as totalChainsPivoted on totalChainsPivoted.`ID_PROD` = id_product

where pr.id_proyect = 5  and (from_unixtime(vi_real_start,'%Y-%m-%d') between '2014-09-01' and '2014-10-30')
group by product
order by pd_product asc
```

**EXPLANATION:**

The table is normalized so I have to do many joins to retrieve the info I need. Basically I'm retrieving information from different tables so I can list the products by family and by brand as they're categorized, to get the MIX, MAX, AVERAGE and MODE prices for those products. The statistics mode is a subquery.

The FISRT CATEGORY, SECOND CATEGORY etc are kinds of stores where the product was sold, so for the statistics sample I use here to get all the prices I need (max, min, etc) I need to get exactly the strores that sample is conformed. This data I get it in form of columns, but I need this to be in a row; based on other Stack Overflow posts, I managed to set those column values as values in rows with the help of the `sum(case when totalChainsByProduct.`CHAIN`.....` statements.

The result set I get is this one:

```
| ID PRODUCT | BRAND | FAMILY | PRODUCT | MIN | MAX | AVERAGE | MODE | SAMPLE SIZE | FIRSTCATEGORY| SECONDCATEGORY | THIRDCATEGORY | FOURTHCATEGORY

'580', 'GreatBrand', 'LineExcellent', 'So great product 16 gr.', '13.75', '2300.00', '430.65', '16.00', '287', '15', '76', '22', NULL
```

That's a single row result set...

So, I don't know how to use the same query I have, get one correct row, and then repeat the query with another ID and add that new row to and keep the first one and so on.

What do I need to do? A temporary table, or perhaps a function?

Comment: You should be able to use `in` with suitable changes to the rest of the query.  Perhaps you can devise a somewhat simpler query and ask a question about that.  Answering a question about a mysterious query is rather difficult.

Comment: 'twould help give you an answer if we could see your query.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I'll try to do my query more readable and add it to the question, thanks

Comment: I've added my SQL and I've also typed an explanation. Hopefully you can help me. Thanks again!

Comment: @GordonLinoff Any ideas? I still can't achieve this u.u Thanks

Comment: @Metafaniel . . . I would suggest that you simplify the query so it is easier to understand the exact problem you are facing.  It is quite hard to follow your query and I suspect there is a simpler version with a similar issue.  Then ask another question (perhaps adding a SQL Fiddle example as well).